# python pickle gives "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'"

Tags: python, python-2.7, pickle

When I try to pickle something, I get an `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'`

An example:

```
import pickle
pickle.dump({"a dict":True},"a-file.pickle")
```

produces:

```
...
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'
```

What's wrong?

Comment: I'd be interested to discuss the downvotes... this question seems trivial, but it would have saved me precious time if it had already been here...

Comment: 'twasn't I, but look at the hover text on the downvote button: "This question doesn't show any research effort…" might be the reason if reason was at play. In general, questioning downvotes is a waste of effort; if they wanted to tell you, they would have.

Comment: if a perfectly good answer to your question is "RTFM", then I could see why someone might downvote

Comment: @MikeMcKerns You know, SO is often (usually?) a faster place to get an answer than the FM, especially when you receive an uninformative exception (which string was it that doesn't have 'write'? perhaps it's "a dict"? so pickle expects dict keys to have write methods?? what's going on??).

Comment: It's interesting the the SO community has given this question the same number of up and down votes - seems the community is divided on the issue!

Comment: @drevicko: **I wouldn't** give you a downvote for your question, but I could see why someone would.  That's all I meant.

Comment: @MikeMcKerns agreed on both points! (: fwiw, I personally like having questions like this here - the FM often annoys me ;) Hmm.. perhaps in time, people who find this Q useful will upvote. Perhaps it's those looking for an interesting question to answer that don't like it?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

It's a trivial mistake: `pickle.dump(obj,file)` takes a `file` object, not a file name.

What I need is something like:

```
with open("a-file.pickle",'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump({"a dict":True},f)
```