# pickle needs 'write' attribute?

Tags: python, pickle

My error when using the program:

```
file must have 'write' attribute
```

My program:

```
import pickle

inp = input()

if inp == "in":
    f = open ("txt.txt", 'wb')
    pickle.dump(f, inp)
    f.close()

if inp == "out":
    f = open ("txt.txt", "rb")
    print(pickle.load(f))
    f.close()
```

Has anyone an idea how to solve this?

Comment: Always start with reading the function documentation.  Your parameters are in the wrong order.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25958824/235698

Answer (score 1):

The `pickle.dump` function has the [following signature](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.dump):

```
pickle.dump(obj, file, protocol=None, *, fix_imports=True, buffer_callback=None)
```

So the file object should be the *second* argument.

So in your case, you would want:

```
pickle.dump(inp, f)
```

Comment: thank u very much, i was very sure it was the other way round but u r right :D
its working thxxx